# get dynamic query in prisma

Tags: prisma, next.js13

**hi there. I use next.js with Prisma and I have hard times fixing this problem.
i need to get catSlug dynamically, but I don't know how. it should come from param (like when my URL is: 'www.my-web.com/cities or [www.my-web.com/experiences'](http://www.my-web.com/experiences%27)).
any idea?**

```
import prisma from "@/helpers/connect";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  const { searchParams } = new URL(req.url);
  const page = searchParams.get("page");

  const POST_PER_PAGE = 4;

  const query = {
    where: { catSlug: "cities" },
    take: POST_PER_PAGE,
    skip: POST_PER_PAGE * (Number(page) - 1),
  };

  try {
    const [posts, count] = await prisma.$transaction([
      prisma.post.findMany(query),
      prisma.post.count(),
    ]);

    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ posts, count, status: 200 }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ message: "Something went wrong!", status: 500 }));
  }
};
```

**and this is my dynamic category page:**

```
import { Container, Pagination, PostList } from "@/components";
import prisma from "@/helpers/connect";
import { getAllPosts, getCategories, getPaginatedPosts } from "@/helpers/utils";
import { Category, Post } from "@/types";
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

// The new getStaticPaths: It generates all versions of this page (cities and experiences) at built time.
export const generateStaticParams = async () => {
  try {
    const categories = await prisma.category.findMany({
      select: { slug: true },
    });

    return categories.map((category) => ({
      category: category.slug,
    }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    throw new Error("error generating params");
  }
};

export default async function CategoryPage({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: { category: string };
  searchParams: { page: number };
}) {
  // Fetch and filter categories by slug
  const category = await prisma.category.findUnique({
    where: {
      slug: params.category,
    },
  });

  if (!category) notFound();

  const page = Number(searchParams.page) || 1;
  const { posts }: { posts: Post[] } = await getPaginatedPosts(page);

  const filteredPosts = posts;

  return (
    <Container>
      <div className="mb-10">
        <h1 className="text-4xl mb-1 font-semibold">{category?.title}</h1>
        <p className="text-lg text-neutral-600">{category?.description}</p>
      </div>

      <div className="mb-24">
        <PostList posts={filteredPosts} />
      </div>

      {/* <Pagination page={page} hasPrev={hasPrev} hasNext={hasNext} /> */}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

i tried to access params in so many ways here. but i failed

Comment: What is the path of your page.tsx file? 
It should be `app/[category]/page.tsx`. is it?

Comment: yes it is. my problem is that i want to get access to params in my route in this address: api/category/route.ts